# Artificial Intelligence project idea

Tags: artificial-intelligence, project, machine-learning

I am looking for a graduation project idea in AI and machine learning field... 
The idea may require front-end user interface to attract users...

I am thinking of how AI and machine learning can help you in daily life..?

Any help/hint about new interesting ideas ?

Thanks

**Edit:**

I am talking about practical ideas that may be used in real life... Not an idea to prove theoretical things...  Something like a OS (or an add on in existing one) that adapt with your way of work... or a word processor that helps you collecting information about what you are writing..

Comment: This is an undergraduate thesis, right?  "Something like a OS (or an add on in existing one) that adapt with your way of work" seems wildly impractical to me.  The second idea seems better.  Why aren't you talking to an adviser and working out a doable topic with them?

Comment: I like the second idea as well. It's pragmatic and also scalable: you could start small, and even a simple implementation might be helpful, but the potential scope is almost unlimited.  You might want to pick a specific domain to give assistance on, possibly something you're already familiar with, such as a favorite history topic, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two ideas:

1. Write a current, robust version of SHRDLU with understandable source code.
2. Write a SHRDLU-like program that manipulates actual code instead of imaginary blocks.  Such a tool could be used for manipulating extremely large, complicated programs, including its *own* code!

Imagine giving commands like the following...

(a) Scan web site X and list any sentences you failed to parse.

(b) Scan document Y and list any grammar rules you didn't need.

(c) Instead of iterating over every element of "proplist" in your "search" function, only process the cdr of "proplist" if the initial call to "lookup" returns nil.  After you make the modification, confirm the sentence "pick up a very very big block" will succeed and the sentence "pick up a very and very big block" will fail.

(d) Your "conjoin" grammar currently requires a coordinator word like "and", but that requirement is wrong.  Split your "coordination" grammar into "syndetic coordination" and "asyndetic coordination" as follows:  conjoins using "and", as in "quickly and quietly, he walked into the bank" are called "syndetic coordinations".  Conjoins without a coordinator, as in "quickly, quietly, he walked into the bank" are "asyndetic coordinations".  Now scan corpus Z to see if fewer sentences fail to parse.

Answer (score 6):

What about an project that uses Markov-Chain text generation to generate answers for Stack Overflow questions? (^__^)

Answer (score 3):

One component of intelligence is imagination.

It wouldn't take much to Google for "artificial intelligence research projects" and see what other people are doing at other schools.  Since it's not a Ph.D., there's no uniqueness requirement for you.

You could also look at Peter Norvig's text to see what's been done before and adapt it.

I'd also recommend doing something with the reams of data that's available to you on the web.  Try thinking about "Programming Collective Intelligence" and "Beautiful Data" to see how you could use information to teach a program how to adapt its behavior based on new information (neural nets, genetic algorithms, ant colony algorithms, etc.)

Answer (score 2):

What interests you?

AI is used in a great many areas, so find something you are passionate about and then see how to use AI for it.

For example, if you are interested in games, then you could find an interesting algorithm for the ghosts in Pac-man to chase, and use some more interesting mazes. You may find someone that is interested in doing a 3D project and they could write a 3D version and your algorithm could be more interesting.

Or, you may be interested in robotics. Again, it would be ideal if you could find someone with an interest in making a robot and you could write the AI part.  So, for example, you could see if you can figure out how to get a robot to determine the difference between a farm crop and a weed/grass.

Basically, your starting point should be on what really interests you.

Answer (score 1):

Perform a clustering on documents, as done by [ex-clusty search engine](http://search.yippy.com/). This clearly is an attractive application.